# Create multiple table into oracle database from input csv file using store procedure

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to create multiple table in oracle database using store procedure. I have a input csv file in below format

```
tablename | column name |column type
abc       |c1,c2,c3     |string,string,string
afg       |c5,c6,c7,c8  |string,timestamp,string,timestamp
...
```

So I will read this file and want to create dynamic table abc and afg.
Question is: how to read the file from store procedure?

Comment: You do not need to read file from stored procedure. You need to read file from java and then call stored procedure with parameters parsed from file

Comment: Where is this file located?  If you want to read it from a stored procedure, the file would need to exist on the server (or a directory mounted on the server).  If the file exists on the machine where the Java application runs, you'd need to read the file from the Java application.  Or if the file exists on the client machine and you're building a three-tiered application, you'd upload the file via the browser and the Java application could pass a `clob` to a stored procedure rather than having either the stored procedure or the Java application read the file.